# How do I estimate $P[|v-\mu| > \epsilon]$ as a function of $\epsilon$?

Tags: probability, self-study, estimation

Problem from: **Learning from Data**

Say I flip $1000$ coins $10$ times each and choose three coins:
$c1$ = the first coin, $c_{\text min}$ = the coin with the minimum frequency of heads, and $c_{\text{rand}}$ = a random coin.  Then let $v_1, v_{\text {min}}, v_{\text {rand}}$ be the fraction of heads flipped for each respective coin.

Assume this experiment is repeated $100000$ times so the resulting experiment results can be neatly organized in an array of shape $(100000,3)$ where each row is $[v_1, v_{\text {min}}, v_{\text {rand}}]_{i^{\text{th}} \text{ result }}$.  Assume each coin is fair so that $\mu = P[\text{ heads }] = P[\text{ tails }] = \frac{1}{2}$

---

Using the experiment results, how would I estimate $P[|v-\mu| > \epsilon]$ as a function of $\epsilon$?

My thoughts are:  $P[|v-\mu| > \epsilon] = 1 - P[|v - \mu| < \epsilon] = 1 - \sum_{k = \text{floor($\mu - \epsilon$)}}^{\text{floor($\mu + \epsilon$)}} P[v = k]$.

But from here I don't really understand what I would do or how I would evaluate $P[v = k]$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How did you get to the term $P[v=k]$ and what do you understand about it? Where do the expressions $\text{floor}(\mu+\epsilon)$ stem from?

Comment: What kind of estimate are you looking for (1) exact calculation/expression of probabilities (2) approximate expression (3) computational estimate using the 100 000 repetitions of the experiment?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Updated.  I am guessing the floor expressions because the binomial is only defined for integers.  I got the term $P[v=k]$ because it's the integer values between $floor(\mu - \epsilon, \mu + \epsilon)$.  The problem says to "plot estimates as a function of $\epsilon$"  I don't know what type of estimates it's explicitly asking for.

Comment: @Oliver_G  could you maybe say few more words of backgrounds about this question. Why are you dealing with this question. E.g. in what kind of course are you getting this? What do you wish to achieve/learn?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I am self studying the book "Learning from Data: a short course" going through every page and attempting all of the exercises and problems and I am unsure how to think about estimating this probability.

Comment: I do not know that book. Can you tell what the point is of the exercise. What is the chapter about and what are you supposed to learn. What is the message from this question, what is the trick that you are supposed to learn, or gain an understanding about?